# mathspec with XeLaTeX produces Greek character `already defined' error

Tags: xetex, mathspec

As per the Title. I am trying to use `\mathspec` so that I can override the default math font.

When I typeset, I am told that the various Greek letters (Gamma, Delta, etc.) have already been defined. I can hit return 11 times to get through them, but that's probably not best way to deal with it...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math]{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Asana Math}
\setprimaryfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Palatino}
\setallsansfonts[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Optima}
\setallmonofonts[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Fira Mono}


\begin{document}
Here's my test: $ \chi^2 + 27 $.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I change the fonts to ones I have, then I get the same error but the error goes if I remove the `[math]` option, do you need that? (In general it's probably recommended to use `unicode-math` rather than `mathspec` these days.)

Comment: The `[math]` option loads `fontspec` without the `no-math` option. I don't think you should.

Comment: Hmm, I must have misunderstood the `mathspec` option: `[math]`. I thought without that, it was using `fontspec` without math. It now runs for me as well and I haven't noticed any missing characters.